# IBM Worklight - Storing large amount of data in offline mode for Windows 7 gadgets

Tags: windows, ibm-mobilefirst, offline-caching

I am creating an application using IBM Worklight for the Windows 7 / Vista Gadgets Environment. I need to store large amount of data (i.e around 100MB) in offline storage. But for the Windows 7 / Vista Gadgets environment we can only use Encrypted Offline Cache, however that has a limit of 5 to 10MB.

Is there another solution for storing large amount of offline data in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

That is an incredibly large amount of data for offline use especially for the web storage which has its limits.

In what form do you need this offline use?

You can use the native database by going through PhoneGap if you need it in that format. Another option is to use the FileSystem via PhoneGap.

Here is a link to some answers about PhoneGap and Web storage options/cases.

[What database does PhoneGap use and what is the size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707201/what-database-does-phonegap-use-and-what-is-the-size-limit)

You can also check out the PhoneGap api on their file system here, http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File    (I referenced version 2.6 because IBM Worklight 6.0 uses 2.6)

For everyone else, if you were using Android or iOS, I would suggest the JSONStore which has a max storage based on the available space (similar to Cordova Storage and Cordova File Storage) for Android and iOS.

Here's a link to IBM infocenter on IBM Worklight 6.0 and the JSONStore feature comparison. It is a great chart that describes the different

Comment: thanks for the reply. can u please suggest how to use phonegap features in IBM worklight?

Comment: There is no Cordova / PhoneGap support for this environment in Worklight. The above does not answer your question...

Comment: does it support for windows 8 phone or desktop?