# how to fetch the data from local database on the phonegap

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

i am going to develop the offline phonegap app, the app will be referred the data from the local database and currently, i have to use wamp server Is there is any possibilities to fetch the data locally and displayed on the phonegap app. thanks for advance

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17HPQIsr2YE  watch this video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hey**
Please follow the below link to find a solution to your problem.

link:-
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570868/storage-of-sqlite-database-using-android-and-phonegap](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSetRowList)

OR

[Have a look here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSetRowList)

Hope it will help you :)

**Thanks**