# How can jQueryMobile app use IndexedDB database?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, indexeddb, nativeapplication

I want to build **jQueryMobile** app using **IndexedDB** technology for databases. While developing in web browser the app is working. How can I convert this app into native android app (using phonegap) and to keep the data from IndexedDB database? 
I know that location of my IndexedDB database is at:

```
C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\
```

So is there a way for my app to use IndexedDB at the mobile devices ?
For conversion I'am using  [phonegap cloud](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) but the converted app does not have access to the database. I'am testing with Nexus 7 tablet. The app on my PC works great.

> **EDIT 1**:
>   I'am testing with Google Nexus 7 tablet. Android version is 4.4.2 so i suppose that IndexedDB is supported on my device. The problem is that I don't have idea how to implement  the file from the location above (what to do with it) while conversion, so that the database would be found on my device. (I'am using [phonegap cloud](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) for conversion).

Comment: Check [this](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb), only android 4.4 supports indexeddb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunatly IndexedDB is not supported by android browser before version 4.4.

Check this page for availability : http://caniuse.com/indexeddb

There seems to be a way, look at Iwona Trąbka's answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624482/phonegap-sqlite-or-indexed-db).

Or you can use something like [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) to encapsulate database access.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link for the support, [INDEXDB SUPPORT](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb)

I had tested it on android 4.3 and it did not worked but here it shows it has support on 4.4.

Also, please go through this blog for [IOS](http://blog.nparashuram.com/2012/10/indexeddb-example-on-cordova-phonegap.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Android 4.x an older version is implemented but on Android 4.4 it should work without plugins. I use a polyfill for iOS and Android which actually uses websql. The polyfill adds the indexedDB API while I isn't actually supported and converts the calls to websql!

websql is supported on android 2+. See the indexedDBShim for details: https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim/

Note: The polyfill isn't perfect, not all methods support an IDDBKeyRange but you can workaround it in most cases. It does workvon iOS 4+ if you want to support iOS in the future.

Edit: Also the answer your question, you can just open the database by name. There is no need to know the actual location on disk.